# Am using git for windows to build .net project

Tags: git

Am using git for windows to build .net project using visual studio online
And while compiling, its throwing an error 
                                                                                Failed to stat file 'C:/agent/_work/0f57256c/Partners-Street-hight/ Ginreeniering/prc/psh next psh/pregsso/ppregressp/ShiPgressoSupplierAccess/Contracts/Service References/ExternalServiceReference/psH.Pgresso.ShiPgressoSupplierAccess.Contracts.ExternalServiceReference.AddAddressResponse.datasource': The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a git issue...

Comment: is it a TFS error, as i haven't found this on forum

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error with git or svn (hard to tell which one was throwing the error) when converting from svn to git/tfs.  The cause of the error was this:

`The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

I had a service reference whos fully qualified namespace/path was longer than 260 characters.  I had to run the conversion from a shorter path on my machine such as c:\temp to get the path under the 260 char limit.  Why windows still has this short file length limit after all these years is a mystery to me.